# Testing String results which both contain \n

Tags: java, newline, stringbuilder

So I am quickly losing my mind trying to answer a question on codewars. The aim of the code challenge is to strip a string down removing all comments from the code.

So I have this code, which does the stripping and gives me the results I'd expect:

```
   public static String stripComments(String text, String[] commentSymbols) {

        boolean ignoreNext = false;
        StringBuilder noCommentString = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if (String.valueOf(c).equals("\n")) {
                currentLine.append("\\n");
                ignoreNext = false;
                noCommentString.append(currentLine.toString().trim());
                currentLine = new StringBuilder();
                continue;
            }
            if (!ignoreNext) {

                for (int j = 0; j < commentSymbols.length; j++) {
                    if (commentSymbols[j].equals(String.valueOf(c))) {
                        ignoreNext = true;
                        noCommentString.append(currentLine.toString().trim());
                        currentLine = new StringBuilder();
                    }
                }
                if (!ignoreNext) {
                    currentLine.append(c);
                }
            }
        }
        return noCommentString.toString();
    }
```

But for some rather strange reason, this test fails:

```
   @Test
    public void stripComments() throws Exception {

        String expected = "apples, pears\ngrapes\nbananas";
        String actual =  StripComments.stripComments("apples, pears # and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples", new String[]{"#", "!"});
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

If I am to evaluate the code the actual String is:

```
apples, pears\ngrapes\nbananas
```

and of course you can see the expected String is:

```
apples, pears\ngrapes\nbananas
```

why on earth is this failing, I'm certain it's something to do with some bizarre \n behaviour

Comment: `currentLine.append("\\n");` sounds very shady. Why are you replacing a legitimate newline (which is what the output expects), with the literal `\n`?

Comment: For that matter, why not just split on newlines and operate on the resulting list?

Comment: Sugar, the reason I left that in was to try botch the results

Comment: As in have a list of Strings @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should append "\n" rather than "\\n". It doesn't require escape character here. Also currentLine.toString().trim(), causes to delete the new line character so avoid it. Rather try using currentLine.toString(). Some system might require to use "\r\n" rather than "\n". Try this if "\n" doesn't work for you.

Comment: Brilliant, I would never have guessed that it was the trim() doing the dirty, thank you